# Global AddOn data is not being loaded

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Recently all my global AddOn data is being ignored when I log in to any of my characters. I noticed since all my UI and add-on settings were as default.

I initially thought that I may have lost all the data due to a crash, but I can see all the files are there in the global `SavedVariables` directory under my `Account` directory.

How do I make WoW load all of the data again?

Comment: Did something change about your computer environment (such as moving the installation to a new computer, new directory structure, or something similar)?

Comment: Do those files inside savedvariables actually contain any useful data? or were they just regenerated when you logged in?

Comment: @Shaun No to all of those.

Comment: @Resorath I can't vouch for all the data but the auction data is there at least.

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug a while ago - it happened after W7 updated something. I studied a bit and found that it was related to the registries in Windows, but I'm not sure what. However, disabling and then enabling all addons worked for me, reloading my addons configs.

I know this isn't an answer, but I don't have rep enough to comment ^^

Answer (score -1):

Remember that with the introduction of a new patch level to the WoW client all addons are disabled automatically and need to be manually reenabled.
WoW was patched to 4.2 last week of course, so check your addons. Some may work still, others may need updating, a few might need replacement.